# How to setup bamboo CI/CD for basic react app

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, bitbucket, terraform, bamboo

Can anyone help me with what are the steps for setting up Continuous integration and continuous deployment for my basic react app on aws.

we are using bamboo and bit bucket.

Comment: bamboo sucks. there's like zero information on how to do basic stuff like having your frontend app deployed with bamboo